Can I pass an argument and sort using ransack
"I want to display the exact ID at the top when searching.
For example:
select * 
from user 
order by user.id = 25 DESC, created_at DESC;

How can I implement this using ransack?"

This can be done with the help of Arel::Table object. Arel is a library that is being used to help us to write complex SQL queries in a easier way. We can get an object by calling arel_table on the model:
arel_user = User.arel_table

Then we need to order the result of our ransack object by using arel_user:
ransacked_object.result.order(arel_user[:id].eq(25).desc)

